# MQL - fetching data from another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, lookup

So I have the following two collections:

- PastLocation
- NowPlaying

Each collection has some data:

Demo Data:

PastListenerLocation has data like:

```
{
  "UUID": "c19c7dd1c7a4f2ca",
  "timestamp":"2023-02-01T22:15:02.000+00:00",
  "location": {
    "coordinates": [
      00.000,
      00.953512
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  }}
```

NowPlaying has data like:

```
{
  "artist": "Carrie Underwood",
  "song": "Garden",
  "type": "S",
  "timeplay":"2023-02-01T22:15:32.000+00:00",
  "history": [
    "c19c7dd1c7a4f2ca"
  ]
}
```

I have tried to use the following query which is fetched using `pastlocation.aggregate` but I am having no luck showing the NowPlaying data in subarray `NowPlayingInfo`

```
[
  {
    /**
     * query: The query in MQL.
     */
    $match: {
      UUID: "c19c7dd1c7a4f2ca",
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-02-01T22:15:02.000+00:00"),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "NowPlaying",
      let: {
        uuid: "$UUID",
        timestamp: {
          $toDate: {
            $multiply: [
              {
                $toLong: "$timestamp",
              },
              1,
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            history: {
              $in: ["$$uuid"],
            },

            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$timeplay",
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        {
                          $toLong: "$$timestamp",
                        },
                        180000,
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    "$timeplay",
                    {
                      $add: [
                        {
                          $toLong: "$$timestamp",
                        },
                        180000,
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            song: 1,
            artist: 1,
            type: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "NowPlayingInfo",
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      NowPlayingInfo: "$NowPlayingInfo",
    },
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few errors in your `$lookup` pipeline part:

1. To use the variable, you should use it within the `$expr` operator.

```
$expr: {
  $and: [
    {
      $in: [
        "$$uuid",
        "$history"
      ]
    },
    // Another condition
  ]
}
```

2. You are comparing the `Timestamp` type with the `long` type. Comparing the values with different types may lead to unexpected and incorrect results. You should compare the value with the same type by converting the `timeplay` value to the `long` type.

```
{
  $gte: [
    {
      $toLong: "$timeplay"
    },
    {
      $subtract: [
        {
          $toLong: "$$timestamp"
        },
        180000
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The complete aggregation query should be:

**Approach 1**

```
db.PastListenerLocation.aggregate([
  {
    //
    // query: The query in MQL.
    $match: {
      UUID: "c19c7dd1c7a4f2ca",
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-02-01T22:15:02.000+00:00")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "NowPlaying",
      let: {
        uuid: "$UUID",
        timestamp: {
          $toDate: {
            $multiply: [
              {
                $toLong: "$timestamp"
              },
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$uuid",
                    "$history"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        {
                          $toLong: "$timeplay"
                        },
                        {
                          $subtract: [
                            {
                              $toLong: "$$timestamp"
                            },
                            180000
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        {
                          $toLong: "$timeplay"
                        },
                        {
                          $add: [
                            {
                              $toLong: "$$timestamp"
                            },
                            180000
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            song: 1,
            artist: 1,
            type: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "NowPlayingInfo"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo  (Approach 1) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQgrXJDIofn)

---

**Approach 2**

Another approach is to compare the `Timestamp` without converting into `long` by adding milliseconds via `$dateAdd` operator.

```
db.PastListenerLocation.aggregate([
  {
    //
    // query: The query in MQL.
    $match: {
      UUID: "c19c7dd1c7a4f2ca",
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-02-01T22:15:02.000+00:00")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "NowPlaying",
      let: {
        uuid: "$UUID",
        timestamp: "$timestamp"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$uuid",
                    "$history"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        "$timeplay",
                        {
                          $dateAdd: {
                            startDate: "$$timestamp",
                            unit: "millisecond",
                            amount: -180000
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        "$timeplay",
                        {
                          $dateAdd: {
                            startDate: "$$timestamp",
                            unit: "millisecond",
                            amount: 180000
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            song: 1,
            artist: 1,
            type: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "NowPlayingInfo"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo (Approach 2) @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aJZyfErhT0F)

Comment: I've noticed that the query takes a really long time, is there away to make the lookup section of the code faster, or at least limit it.

Not 100% sure why it is going so slow. I know that the collection has close to 897k documents in it.